# How to pass multiple file extensions to TDirectory.GetFiles?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

`TDirectory.GetFiles` has a parameter called [`SearchPattern`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles). Embarcadero's documentation says

> The mask used when matching file names (for example, "*.exe" matches all the executable files).

However, I want to pass multiple file types. I get those types from a `FilterComboBox.Mask`. So, it is a string that looks like `'*.txt;*.rtf;*.doc'`.

I have tried to pass that string directly to `GetFiles` and it doesn't work. Do I have to parse it, break it into pieces and feed every individual piece to `GetFiles`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The RTL code behind `GetFiles` calls [`Masks.MatchesMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Masks.MatchesMask) to test for a match to your search pattern. This function only supports masking against a single mask.

The alternative is to use the `GetFiles` overload that admits a `TFilterPredicate`. You supply a predicate that tests whether or not a name matches your pattern.

```
uses
  StrUtils, Types, Masks, IOUtils;

function MyGetFiles(const Path, Masks: string): TStringDynArray;
var
  MaskArray: TStringDynArray;
  Predicate: TDirectory.TFilterPredicate;
begin
  MaskArray := SplitString(Masks, ';');
  Predicate :=
    function(const Path: string; const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean
    var
      Mask: string;
    begin
      for Mask in MaskArray do
        if MatchesMask(SearchRec.Name, Mask) then
          exit(True);
      exit(False);
    end;
  Result := TDirectory.GetFiles(Path, Predicate);
end;
```

Do note that `MatchesMask` creates and destroys a heap allocated [`TMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Masks.TMask) every time it is called. I can well imagine that being a performance bottleneck over a long search. In which case you could create an array of `TMask` objects from `MaskArray`. And use those in the predicate to test. I've no idea whether this is a valid concern or not, just something that occurred to me whilst perusing the code.

Comment: Nice one. +1   It sort of breaks when files with a semi-colon in the name are used, but that's not the fault of this routine. I never understood why they didn't use something like a pipe to separate masks.

Comment: Yeah, obviously you can choose your sep char from one of the illegal file name chars

Comment: > I've no idea whether this is a valid concern or not - - - I guess it is since there are millions of files. Good catch.