# Using MatchesMask to filter several different filenames

Tags: delphi

When using TMask from the unit System.Masks I wondered if it is possible to filter a set of different file names (or any other strings). If so, how can I filter for something like *.foo and *.bar?

Using a ';' between the different fields does not work (obviously, after reading the source code).

While with something like *.[fb][oa][or] it's possible to filter *.foo and *.bar files, it would also filter *.far, *.boo and so on.

So far I haven't found time to fully understand the original source code. In particular I wonder what the 'msMBCSLiteral' is used for. Can this be useful in this case? Or are there other ways to achieve this?

PS: I'm aware about how to solve filtering by other means (write some custom code for the filtering). However, since I'd like to reuse some already existing code, I want to use TMask.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. I can't find documentation that explicitly states that, but it seems to follow from the description of MatchesMask. It's also stated in the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726756/how-to-pass-multiple-file-extensions-to-tdirectory-getfiles

Comment: Aren't regular expressions available? You're using a recent version of Delphi, according to your use of `System.Masks` and not just `Masks`. A regex would be really simple in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no facility in the `MatchesMask` function for detecting two different sets of characters in parallel. The `msMBCSLiteral` state is for detecting the lead byte of a multibyte character, not for detecting either of two branches.

To match two different masks, call the function twice:

```
if MatchesMask(filename, '*.foo') or MatchesMask(filename, '*.bar') then
  // ...
```

You could also use a regular expression; `\.(foo|bar)$` would work, provided you set the flag for ignoring case.

If you have a library that supports Bash-style masks, then you could use `*.{foo,bar}`. I'm not aware of any such libraries for Delphi, but that doesn't mean you couldn't find one if you looked.

Comment: Unfortunately, the library I use expects a (one) TMask where the MatchesMask call is performed internally.

Comment: As there don't seem to be a chance to make it working, I tend to accept this answer. However, I still wait a few days until I do so. Maybe someone comes up with a creative solution for this.