# TDirectory::GetFiles listing ignoring case on iOS (FMX, C++)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

The code below lists files that have extension .cfg and it works fine on Win32.  But, on iOS if i have a file that a user named with caps for the extension (e.g. test.CFG) then i miss it. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726756/how-to-pass-multiple-file-extensions-to-tdirectory-getfiles) using Delphi that might work using `TDirectory::TFilterPredicate` but i don't know how to implement in C++Builder.

```
TStringDynArray list;
TSearchOption searchOption;
UnicodeString DocsPath;
int lenDocsFolder;

DocsPath = System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath();
lenDocsFolder = DocsPath.Length();
searchOption = TSearchOption::soTopDirectoryOnly;
try
{
  list = TDirectory::GetFiles(DocsPath, "*.cfg", searchOption);
}
catch (...)
{
    ShowMessage("Incorrect path or search mask");
    return;
}
```

I suppose i can just run a `*.cfg` block of code followed by a `*.CFG` but i'm hoping there is a cleaner approach.

Comment: Well... there are 8 permutations of lower/upper case 3 char strings. Are you going to run through all of them? That doesn't seem like a viable solution to me.

Comment: "*I found this post using Delphi that might work using TDirectory::TFilterPredicate but i don't know how to implement in C++Builder*" - this is *literally* converted by Embarcadero's documentation. See [How to Handle Delphi Anonymous Methods in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B), the C++ example provided uses `TDirectory::GetFiles()` with a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I'm not used to C++. But this applies to both C++ and Delphi.

You are calling:

```
TDirectory.GetFiles(
   const Path, SearchPattern: string;
   const SearchOption: TSearchOption): TStringDynArray;
```

If you instead call this overloaded version:

```
TDirectory.GetFiles(
   const Path, SearchPattern: string;
   const SearchOption: TSearchOption;
   const Predicate: TFilterPredicate): TStringDynArray;
```

you should be able to get what you need.

The TFilterPredicate type is defined as:

```
TFilterPredicate = reference to function(
   const Path: string;
   const SearchRec: TSearchRec): Boolean;
```

and should be the correct way to override the way files are matched.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `Using a Lambda Expression` from the link Remy posted in comment.  I got an `E2188 Expression syntax`error until i disabled the classic Borland compiler.  The code works great for simple predicate (on both Win32 and iOS).

```
  String ext(".cfg");
  files = TDirectory::GetFiles(CalcPath,
                      [ext](const String Path, const System::Sysutils::TSearchRec &SearchRec) -> bool
                      {
                        return ExtractFileExt(SearchRec.Name) == ext;
                      });
```

Now, how do i modify the extension string to return results for both .cfg and .CFG at same time?

```
  String ext(".cfg");  // works fine
  String ext(".cfg;.CFG");  // finds nothing
```